# IONOS WordPress Hosting Login Problems

Tags: wordpress, authentication, web-hosting, ionos, ultimate-member

When I register a new User on my own register form and confirm the email, it redirects me to the profile page and I’m logged in. But when I try to use my own login form it doesn’t do anything. When I do login with WordPress under
`*/wp-login` everything works just fine.
I am using UltimateMember plugin btw.

I have tried to redo the login form, but nothing worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.